# Adding spans to a parent with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I wrote a JavaScript function that takes the current number of spans of the class `mini` in the paragraph element with an id `mega`, which is at least 1, and if there are less than 4, adds enough to make 4. If there was no second `mini`, then the second `mini`, which the function should create, should say `2`<sup>`nd`</sup>, if a third one is created, it should say `3`<sup>`rd`</sup>, and if a fourth is created, it should say `4`<sup>`th`</sup>. For example, if there are already 2 `mini` spans, the program, should add 2 more, the first one added saying `3`<sup>`rd`</sup> and the second one saying `4`<sup>`rd`</sup>. Here's the code:

```
function addSpans(currentNumOfSpans)
{
    var mega       = document.getElementById("mega");
    var mini       = document.createElement("span");
    mini.className = "mini";
    if (currentNumOfSpans < 4)
    {
        if (currentNumOfSpans < 3)
        {
            if (currentNumOfSpans < 2)
            {
                mini.innerHTML = "2<sup>nd</sup>;
                mega.appendChild(mini);
            }
            mini.innerHTML = "3<sup>rd</sup>;
            mega.appendChild(mini);
        }
        mini.innerHTML = "4<sup>th</sup>;
                mega.appendChild(mini);
    }
}
```

Soooo.... If `currentNumOfSpans` is 3, it works fine, and adds `4th` to mega. However, if `currentNumOfSpans` is 1 or 2, while it should add `2nd3rd4th` or `3rd4th`, respectively, it just adds `4th`. Can someone help me figure out what's wrong with this. Any help's appreciated, thanks!

*Note: If you notice any typos, please comment or edit, but they aren't the problem, I've checked over my code in a syntax checker, but I often make errors in my code on SO because I use a tiny phone keyboard. So basically, typo's, whichI probably made, aren't the real problem. Thanks!*

Comment: `currentNumOfSpans != CurrentNumOfSpans`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example included a few typos, most of which could be found by running your code through a debugger, like http://jshint.com.

However, I would use a more functional approach. The following method is not hard coded like yours, so you could use it for multiple elements, or use a different number of spans with very minimal changes to the usage, I've shown this in the demo below.

```js
function getSuffix(i) {
    var j = i % 10, k = i % 100;
    if (j == 1 && k != 11) return i + "<sup>st</sup>";
    if (j == 2 && k != 12) return i + "<sup>nd</sup>";
    if (j == 3 && k != 13) return i + "<sup>rd</sup>";
    return i + "<sup>th</sup>";
}
function addSpans(scope, length) {
    var spans = scope.querySelectorAll('.mini');
    var current = length - (length - spans.length);
    while(current < length) {
       var span = document.createElement('span');
       span.className = 'mini';
       span.innerHTML = getSuffix(++current);
       scope.appendChild(span);
    }
}

var wrap  = document.querySelector('.wrap'), divs; 
var clone = wrap.cloneNode(true);

wrap.parentNode.appendChild(clone);

divs = wrap.querySelectorAll('.mega');
for(var i in Object.keys(divs)) addSpans(divs[i], 4);

divs = clone.querySelectorAll('.mega');
for(var i in Object.keys(divs)) addSpans(divs[i], 6 + (i * 2));
```

```css
.mega { font-size: 0; } .mini { display: inline-block; width: 40px; font-size: 16px; }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="mega"></div>
    <div class="mega"><span class="mini">1<sup>st</sup></span></div>
    <div class="mega"><span class="mini">1<sup>st</sup></span><span class="mini">2<sup>nd</sup></span></div>
    <div class="mega"><span class="mini">1<sup>st</sup></span><span class="mini">2<sup>nd</sup></span><span class="mini">3<sup>rd</sup></span></div>
    <div class="mega"><span class="mini">1<sup>st</sup></span><span class="mini">2<sup>nd</sup></span><span class="mini">3<sup>rd</sup></span><span class="mini">4<sup>th</sup></span></div>
</div>
```